# When I pass jquery datepicker date in ajax, php finds index error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Here is my demo.php

```
<div class="form-message"></div>
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="ownerBdate" placeholder="Enter your Bday" type="text" data-date-end-date="0d" autocomplete="off"  required=""/>
    <label class="ownerBdayLabel">Birthday</label>
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="zmdi zmdi-calendar"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
    <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
        <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
        <button id="submit" class="login100-form-btn">Register</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#dateBirthday").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            changeYear: true
    });
        $("#submit").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var ownerBdate = $("ownerBdate").val();
            $(".form-message").load("demo-validator.php",{
                ownerBdate : ownerBdate,
            submit : submit
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is the demo-validator.php

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
    $ownerBdate = $_POST['ownerBdate'];
    echo $ownerBdate;
```

?>

Problem is when I click submit button it gives me an error where it says undefined index in my php. I have tried all the way I can.

Comment: Please elaborate on 'all the way I can'.

Comment: like jquery code changes or ajax code changes. even I tried ajax with 'GET' method to pass the value. But it shows the Undefined index in PHP.

Comment: Please open the inspector and provide the request data from the network tab. To be sure, that problem is on the php side. And what is {submit : submit} ? where is the var `submit`. Can't also find #dateBirthday in provided html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change code to use id instead of name var ownerBdate = $("ownerBdate").val(); and

```
var ownerBdate = $("#dateBirthday").val(); // check with console or alert value coming or not.
```

you are not getting selected date value.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I have corrected this portion.

Answer (score 0):

alert your ownerBdate:

```
var ownerBdate = $("ownerBdate").val();
alert(ownerBdate);
```

what is your 'submit' variable? Define it too.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have alerted and then after going through some more checking, I found my bug.

Answer (score 0):

to select an item by name with jQuery:

```
var ownerBdate = $("[name ='ownerBdate']").val();
```

to select an element by its id:

```
var ownerBdate = $("[id ='ownerBdate']").val();
```

or

```
var ownerBdate = $("#datepicker").val();
```